# Eclipse classpath cannot find JDBC file

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) on a MacBook Pro, OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.  I recently installed PostgreSQL 10.  PostgreSQL 9.4 still exists; the connection for both being 5432.

If 10 is connected without 9.4 connected, I get the following error when I try to run the project:  “Launch configuration EclipseStarter references closed project PDFBox2”.

Previous to this state I was getting the following error:  *’Launching FirstWbGuiPaniniIndexing (3)’ has encountered a problem.
The archive: /Users/davidellisrogers/Documents/workspace/Panini Test Files 4/PaniniIndexing Working current CODE/src/lib/postgressql-9.4-1200/jdbc4.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.*

I looked for  … /PaniniIndexing Working current CODE/src/lib/postgressql-9.4-1200/jdbc4.jar where the launch could not find it.  It exists there.  The current message “Launch configuration EclipseStarter references closed project PDFBox2” indicates to me that it is still looking for 9.4 jar.
(I have tried the solution suggestion online about a dummy file, but it doesn’t work.)
Next, I did the following, found on the internet:

> 1-Right CLick on your project folder, Choose Build Path > Configure
>   Build Path 
>   2-Select Libraries Tab and delete any arbitrary library
>   present there.

So I removed 2 postgresql 9.4 entries.  Tested, still same error.
Next, I removed 4 PDFBox entries.  Refreshed, still get same error.
3-Click on Add Library option, Select JRE System Library and click Next.

How do I go about telling it to look for the postgresql 10? (which I assume is the problem)

Comment: "the connection for both being 5432" <= This can't be true. Check the ports, one is most likely 5432, the other 5433.

Answer (score -1):

Just checked.  Both PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostgreSQL 10 have the connection port set to 5432.  Am working with 10 now.  Note:  I work with only one open at a time.